# Value normalization for both B&W and colored photos

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to build a convnet for facial recognition. I'm using keras and this command to create generator and normalize value:

```
ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

Since my dataset is composed by B&W and colored photos, is it correct to apply value normalization (using a 1/255) or this would distort B&W photos?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to rescale images as long as you rescale all of them equally.

But you will probably face difficulties in modeling if your black and white photos have only one channel. (If they have 3 channels, just like the colored images, it's ok).